# setting the precision

Tags: matlab

I want to set the precision to 24 bits while using matlab. Is this possible without using vpa?
because vpa is consuming lot of time since I am calling vpa more than 8000 times.

Please help

Comment: Can you explain why you need 24 bits? Are you trying to simulate the behavior of a 24-bit fixed point processor?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab uses by default the data type `double`, which has 64 bits precision, so there is no need to use vpa, if you want *at least* 24 bits precision.

If it is really your intention to decrease precision, you could use variables of data type `single` with 32 bits precision.

If you need exactly 24 bits precision, vpa may be the way to go. Alternatively, you could artificially reduce the precision of the result after each computation step.

Comment: sorry to explicitily mention the problem!! I need 24 bits precision after the decimal.

Comment: @mary it would help if you could explain the context. As Hilmar wrote, *why* do you need 24 bits precision? – "After the decimal", i.e. you mean you need fixed point numbers?